# How to setup a SVN

Tags: windows, svn, networking

We are a small team (undergraduates) works on some freelance projects. we need to have a SVN. how could i do this? how does it work? do i need a dedicated server? or could it be done with a virtual server? Please clarify me.

Thank You.

Comment: you might want to consider a distributed SCM like Mercurial - the big advantage is that you don't need a central server at all

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are not familiar with Subversion, you might be, in your circumstances, better off reading up on Git. Git is a distributed version control system and one of its main advantages is that each user has a full copy of the repository. This means that your repository doesn't have to be up on the Internet at all times.

Another big advantage of Git is that you can submit *patches* (what Git uses for Source Code Changes) without a network. You simply create a patch, which can be transfered via email, a patchfile sitting on public file area like [Dropbox](http://dropbox.com), or even a USB thumb drive that's passed back and forth. In fact, you can trade patches with anyone and not with the *main* repository.

That means if you have four users, User A and User B can trade *patches* back and forth in one project while User B and User C can trade them back and forth in another project. In the end, you can all submit the changes to User D who would have all the changes.

If you can't use Git, Subversion works well in many circumstances. It'll work on virtual servers, and can use multiple protocols for communication. The simplest is probably the _svnserve` that comes with Subversion. You can setup basic security with *svnserve* very easily. Subversion is very light weight, so it takes up little processing bandwidth.

SourceForge is the most widely known free Subversion hosting site. Google Project Hosting is also a good Subversion hosting provider. Or, if you already have a system that's sitting on the Internet, you could just run svnserve and do your own hosting from that.

If you have your own system, and feel like being really fancy, you can use httpd to run Subversion under http or https.

Take a look at the on line [Red Bean Subversion](http://svnbook.com) manual on the Web. It's one of the best open source documents around.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the comment. if i set up TortoiseSVN in my local PC. would it be possible for my other team members (works from different locations) to access the source code through the support of web or http?

Answer (score 1):

[uberSVN](http://www.ubersvn.com/) has a nice web interface if you want something easy to administer

Answer (score 0):

If you're a complete beginner, and don't want to learn the ins and outs, go with a hosted service. Many have free offerings like http://beanstalkapp.com or http://xp-dev.com/

Here's an SO question discussing many of the hosted providers
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69384/opinion-of-hosted-svn-providers

Comment: Yup. im a complete beginner. thanks a lot for the suggestions. can u explain me how does it work?

Comment: I have hosted some sites on bluehost. would it be possible to setup a separate SVN in that web server to maintain our projects?

Answer (score 0):

It would run fine on a virtual server, it has very little overhead. Here's a quick tutorial on setting it up on [Windows](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2008/04/setting-up-subversion-on-windows.html) (since you tagged it Windows).

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to install Subversion on Windows is to use [VisualSVN server](http://www.visualsvn.com/server/). It integrates into your services and provides a nice GUI for management.

Whether you should use VM or a real PC highly depends on your usage. VM has very limited resources and therefore might introduce lags on heavy usage (large projects > 50mb, frequent commits and checkouts, frequent polling). For less than 20 developers VM should be just fine.

Comment: if i set up VisualSVN server in my local PC. would it be possible for my other team members (works from different locations) to access the source code through the support of web or http?

Comment: You will have to forward the port (usually 80) through your forewall/nat.